# Command "jobs" doesnt work on terminal (shell,bash)

Tags: bash, shell, command, jobs

I'm just trying to make a simple script which involves the command "jobs", but it doesnt seem to work, it doesn't even get recogniced by "man"... No idea what's going on :S.

Comment: `jobs` is a shell builtin command - `man bash` to read about it. How is it "not working"? What are you expecting vs. what you are observing?

Comment: it's supposed to show me the status of the jobs suspended or in second plane, or so said my teacher...

Comment: Not sure what "in second plane" means, but I would add this - `jobs` will show you the background and suspended jobs *started by this instance of the shell*. So if your script doesn't start anything in the background (i.e. `some_command &`), there will be no output from `jobs`. It won't report things that were started by the parent shell.

Comment: Post that as a solution. That was it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jobs` will only report on background and/or suspended processes that were spawned by the instance of the shell in which `jobs` is being run. So using it in a script will be of limited usefulness (but should be fine for just reporting what's going on to the script user), as only things that were spawned earlier in the script and either backgrounded or suspended in some other way will be known to the shell instance running the script.

Answer (score 1):

You need to be running an interactive shell for the `jobs` command to work - job control in this manner is used by users, not by scripts.

You should be able to use the `jobs -p` command to get the pids of running background tasks (jobs), which may accomplish what you're trying to do. This should display all the pids of subprocesses, which can be checked/monitored separately.

Answer (score 1):

`jobs` is a bash builtin (if you think of it, it actually doesn't really make sense to have a system command that controls job processes launched from a shell). You'll find more information about that command by:

- Issuing `help jobs` in your terminal
- Reading the [corresponding section](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Job-Control) in the bash reference manual.

Answer (score 0):

Install the POSIX man pages. The package should be named something like "manpages-posix-dev" or similar.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a linux / unix command called `jobs`.

Both `which jobs` and `sudo apt-get jobs` on ubuntu finds nothing.

If it's a local binary, check your `$PATH` to make sure that it's included.

Comment: `type jobs` would probably have found it, depending on the shell you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Use the ps command to find your processes from a shell script